# Bing Map on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, bing-maps, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to change the viewport of a map within a Windows phone 8.1 app. I have to set the center (that it works) and the lowerLeft/upperRight coordinates to set the bounds of the map, but I have just the ZoomLevel property that can't help me to set the bounds of the map with precision.

This is what I have:

**XAML**

```
xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
...
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="myMap" MapServiceToken="<token>"/>
```

**CODE**

```
this.myMap.Center = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 46.85, Longitude = 8.94});
```

Now I want to set the upperRight and lowerLeft corner to set the bounds. I saw this article [HERE](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24124.windows-phone-8-map-control-how-to-get-map-bounds-area-c-xaml.aspx) but it doesn't work for me.. the `ConvertGeoCoordinateToViewportPoint` doesn't exist with the namespace `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps` and I don't know why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a specific method to set the bounds of the current `MapControl` which is `TrySetViewBoundsAsync`, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn637065.aspx

And you might be interested in the `GeoboundingBox` class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.devices.geolocation.geoboundingbox.aspx

And here is an example (Map is your MapControl):

```
List<BasicGeoposition> basicPositions = new List<BasicGeoposition>();
basicPositions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 50, Longitude = 3 });
basicPositions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 55, Longitude = 8 });
basicPositions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 42, Longitude = 0 });

this.Map.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(GeoboundingBox.TryCompute(basicPositions), null, MapAnimationKind.Default);
```

Comment: You are welcome. Also, don't forget to use the second parameter of this TrySetViewBoundsAsync method as it can be really useful to set a padding on the view you want to get. Cheers.

Comment: I just tried this and it does nothing. TrySetViewBoundsAsync returns false all the time except when MapAnimationKind.None is set, but still does nothing